# Density derivatives problem

Tags: probability-distributions, derivatives

Following problem has been bothering me for a bit. Imagine a n-dimensional vector V and its density defined as 
$$
f(V): R^n \rightarrow R.
$$

I would like to calculate the derivative of the following expression
$$
c{f'(V) \over f(V)},
$$
where f'(V) is the first derivative wrt V.

If I write the standard derivative 
$$
c{f''(V) f(V) - f'(V)^Tf'(V) \over f(V)f(V)},
$$
the dimensions do not match as f''(V) is n x n matrix and the remaining terms are numbers.

Do you have any ideas on how to calculate the this derivative?

Comment: Are you trying to compute the derivative w.r.t. $V$ of a function $g$ s.t. $V\mapsto g(V)$, with $g(V):\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$?

Comment: Trying to compute derivative wrt V of function g = f'(V)/f(V) with g being a map from R^n->R, correct

Answer (score 0):

The formula needs only a slight adjustment: 
$$c\,\frac{f''(V) f(V) - f'(V)f'(V)^T} { f(V)f(V)} $$
where $f'(V)f'(V)^T$ is the outer / Kronecker product, also written as $ f'(V)\otimes f'(V)$. Now both terms in the numerator are $n\times n$ matrices.

To see why this works, it helps to consider the simpler problem: derivative of $fG$ where $f$ is a scalar function and $G$ is a vector function. It also helps to focus on partial/directional derivatives first, as they do not change the type of function. For every $i=1,\dots,n$ we have
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} (fG) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\,G + f\,\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_i}$$
which is a vector function. Stacking them into a matrix, you'll see that the first term on the right  becomes $ f' \otimes G$ while the second becomes $f G''$.